# How to write a regex to match HEX value with variables declaration?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regex to match a string that may contains one of the following:

1. Valid Hex number - e.g., "0xa4" (`0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+`)
2. Variable definition - e.g., "$my_var" (`\$[0-9a-zA-Z_]+`)
3. Combination of item#1 and #2 - e.g., "0xa$my_var" (`??`)

I tried:

`^(?:0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+|\$[0-9a-zA-Z_]+)$` - but this doesn't support rule #3

`^(?:0[xX][$0-9a-zA-Z]+)$` - it supports all criteria but also match `0x1z` which is of course not a valid HEX (violates rule#1)

Looking for help from the community...

Comment: Well if you have “a or b” already implemented, then you could simply add “ab” as a third alternative … `^a|b|ab$^`

Comment: `^(?:0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+(?:\$[0-9a-zA-Z_]+)?|\$[0-9a-zA-Z_]+)$`? BTW, variable regex should be probably `\$[A-Za-z_]\w*`.

Comment: Please specify programming language you're using in tags

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks - so simply.. wonder how did i miss that option...

Comment: So, is that all? Don't you want to also match #2 and #1 combination?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: your regex plus minor modifications supports all 3 rules now.

Comment: @NirMH I posted an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex based on an anchored alternation group with one branch containing both patterns, with one of them being optional:

```
^(?:0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+(?:\$[0-9a-zA-Z_]+)?|\$[0-9a-zA-Z_]+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eOw7Yg/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+` - `0`, `x` or `X`, 1+ hex chars
  - `(?:\$[0-9a-zA-Z_]+)?` - an optional sequence of `$` char and 1+ word chars
- `|` - or

  - `\$` - a `$` char
  - `[0-9a-zA-Z_]+` - 1+ word chars
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Generally speaking I agree with your note - variables usually starts with alpha char - but on my application - the string I match against this `Regex` supports variables that start with digit (e.g., `$0`) - thanks again

Comment: @NirMH Ok, I see, I removed the note. If my answer turned out helpful, please also consider upvoting.